# Android real network connection status

Tags: android, android-networking

How to get to know the real connectivity state of the device. In my application I registered to the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent. I receive intents, and they say, that there is connectivity on the device:

```
ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY from intent == false

NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
ni.isAvailable() == true
ni.isConnected() == true
```

And that is right, device is connected, for example, to the wifi point and the signal strength is ok, but application can't connect to the server because internet access is currently broken on the providers side. It looks like device is know about this problem because it grayed wifi icon on the status bar.

How to get to know the real state of the internet connection?

Comment: See comment under gabi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to check your device internet connection. I hope it will help you.

> ```
>  public static boolean IsNetConnected(Context mContext)
> {
>     boolean NetConnected = false;
>     try
>     {
>         ConnectivityManager connectivity =
>                 (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>         if (connectivity == null)
>         {
>             NetConnected = false;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
>             if (info != null)
>             {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
>                 {
>                     if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
>                     {
>                         NetConnected = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     catch (Exception e)
>     {
>         NetConnected = false;
>     }
>     return NetConnected;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you are right. It's not a 100% accurate way to detect your connection status, but you may try

```
public static boolean hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please note that google may be restricted in some countries

Comment: That answer is closest, but it's still not correct. You may get a 200 from www.google.com, but it may not be Google, but rather an interstitial page or hotspot landing page. Instead of checking google and looking for the response-code, the device should check a known webpage and inspect the returned content.

Comment: if you're thinking like this, you won't find a 100% accurate solution... think that someone may screw a wifi router's NAT table and you may receive a good answer even from pentagon's home page...

Comment: Baloney. Your solution will fail at any hotspot at Starbucks, McDonald's, Airport, GoGo, Wayport, etc., until the device is properly signed in. In the real world, your code will fail to detect inaccessible internet 50% of the time.

Comment: Yes, I can do it in this way (I thought about it), but my question is something different, i.e. if Android knows the real state, HOW CAN I GET THIS INFO. Maybe the system do it in the same way, but why I need to do the same things if OS already does it. I just want to know about.

Comment: I think that os may know it sync fails repeatedly (see settings->accounts) and there is a red icon if sync failed (incorrect password or no connection or other cause, I think os can see the main cause of why sync fails)